# I want to know if this way of making a table element is a good or not good?

Tags: html, html-table

I have a condition, 
shown in this image:

[image]

It is only allow to use very simple HTML TABLE element to solve.

I wonder my this solution is it the best already?

http://jsbin.com/exazif/

to look the code: http://jsbin.com/exazif/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Are you strict about the width and the height of the table cells or they can vary?

Comment: strict, the condition will not be implemented, only for table element skill training purpose

Answer (score 0):

If you must use a `<table>`, this method is good. However you should not write `colspan="250"`. Colspan is not designed for that. If you do not have to use a `<table>` you could use floated div's.

To be honest, there is a big debate about what is better: tables or divs. [Read more about it here.](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/04/08/from-table-hell-to-div-hell/)

This is pretty [good tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) on basic tables.

Comment: must use table, this is a skill training question on table, i know div can do even better

Comment: nothing do with basic table anymore, this practice something like test your skill whether you can use div and table , to solve a layout problem , obviously table will be much more suffer , and div is the modern way

Comment: As I said your table is OK. But your usage of colspan is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You should give your td tags ids and then use css instead of the outdated html-attributes.

css

```
table {
  border: none;
  width: 800px;
  border-collapse: collapse; /* instead of cellspacing */
}
td {
  padding: 0;
}
td#first_first {
  background-color: 'red';
  width: 400px;
}
td#first_second {
  background-color: 'blue';
  width: 400px;
}
```

And in your html

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td id="first_first">400x200</td>
  <td id="first_second">400x200</td>
 </tr>
...
</table>
```

Colspan means for how many columns a td cell extends. So in your code it's not used right. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td

Comment: Oops, just realized, that question is very old.